# Weblogic 12c with JSF1.2 migration issue

Tags: richfaces, weblogic12c, jsf-1.2

I am getting following deployment error on weblogic12c.

User defined listener org.primefaces.optimus.listener.ContextListener failed: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "com.wwl.integration.web.ui.CustomAjaxValidator.broadcast(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, com/wwl/integration/web/ui/CustomAjaxValidator, and its superclass loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type javax/faces/event/FacesEvent used in the signature.

Comment: By the looks of it whatever you're trying to deploy is built on some library the version of which is not compatible with the current one. And it doesn't seem to have anything to do with RichFaces.

Comment: Hello Makhiel, do you mean JSF1.2 does not support by weblogic 12c. 
I have done the following : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP197

Comment: You're either not using the correct library or you have not changed your app to work with the new library. I don't know if it's JSF or something else.